Is it proper to use integral to sum terms of the binomial expansion?
Lets say we have developed a formula to calculate the value of the term which is l distant from the maximum term of the expansion for the expression of $(a+b)^n$. Lets say M represents maximum term and Q represets the term l distant from the M.
Now I want to sum all of the terms between the M and Q. Can I use the integration which means calculating the area under the curve between the point M and Q?
I feel using integration is wrong because we want to sum the terms and value of the terms are represented by the points on the graph not by the area under the curve. The reason I am asking this question is I came an across an expression on the Stigler's book 'The History of Statistics The Measurement of Uncertainty before 1900'. It says:
"Having shown the feasibility of calculating $M/2^n$ and $Q/2^n$, there remained the task of summing these terms, say, from $p =-\frac 1 2\sqrt{n}$ to $p =\frac 1 2\sqrt{n}$. In his first attempt to deal with this in 1730, De Moivre had contented himself with stating a quadrature formula, without giving any numerical examples. He had shown that the binomial curve had inflection points at $p=\pm\frac1 2\sqrt{n}$. Therefore, between these points the curve could beexpected to be reasonably well approximated by a quadratic function of p,and the area under the curve (or the sum of the terms) could be found from a three-point quadrature formula appropriate to quadratic functions."
Can someone please explain why we use integration to find the sum?I hope my question is clear enough to understand.
Thank you very much.

Please use MathJax whenever you type a formula on this site. It’s pretty easy. You just enclose your formulae into the $ signs, for the most part.
